# Jquery script for document preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, components, preview

Do you know any components from `jQuery` with which you can preview `.doc,.pdf,.jpg` .... files in browser ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by preview? JPGs are rendered natively in all browsers, PDF files can probably be rendered somehow even without adobe reader installed. Are you looking for a QuickLook-ish thing?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to keep it all native inside the browser you can display images on their own and pdfs with [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

If you only need to display it somehow I advise you to look at [Google docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer?pli=1) (officially discontinued, see below) which allows you lots of different files and which you can next embed in one of the scripts altschuler mentioned. (See my comment to his answer why those tools alone don't do the trick)

Supported file types by google docs viewer

> - Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
> - Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
> - Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
> - Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
> - Apple Pages (.PAGES)
> - Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
> - Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
> - Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
> - Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
> - Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
> - PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
> - TrueType (.TTF)
> - XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
> - Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)

Although I wouldn't recommend this usage on production or professional systems, you can still use the system as described [here](https://googlesystem.blogspot.cz/2015/02/google-docs-viewer-page-no-longer.html).

Comment: This is no longer available. Google has discontinued this.

Comment: Odd. Seems like a hack / unreliable functionality. If this shouldn't be used on PROD, why is it posted as part of an answer? People obviously want a solution that can go to production and providing functionality that meets their question will only open doors for them to use it to go-to-market sooner, and fix it later.

Comment: @1337GameDev Because not everything people work on is professional or needs production quality solutions ;-) .

Comment: True, but it just encourages terrible and frustrating design...   Obviously everything shouldn't be perfect, but i feel providing "hack" solutions will only introduce issues in the long run, even for hobby projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a lightbox feature. Lightbox is the common name for (pre)viewing things in an overlay, so to say.

There are a great deal to choose from, here's a few:

- http://gettopup.com (try the #2 example, this looks a lot like quicklook).
- http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox
- http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox

How you want to show .doc and .pdf files is another issue.

Comment: Please note that if you embed doc and pdf files in one of these scripts it will work in *some* browsers and computers (depending on the software available) but on *most* it will present the file for download.