# Display file preview before upload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, file-upload

I can display a preview of an image before to upload it, but how can I do the same using a pdf or a simple txt file? Here's the code I found for the images:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>

function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

I would like suggestions using an AngularJs approach. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery script for document preview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885824/jquery-script-for-document-preview)

Comment: How you gonna display image in plain text file?

Comment: Well, do you think that there is no way to show a preview of a text file? or a pdf? or something else?

Comment: simply use an iframe tag instead of an img tag

Comment: @dandavis could be a workaround..nice thanks

Comment: yeah, iframe also show images, so you can use it for about any content that can be viewed. note that pdfs might download instead of displaying, according to the browser settings.

Comment: yes, i've seen...this could be a problem..do you think there is a way to prevent it and only display the content?

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/